# Getting the name of a random number generated in a void method

Tags: java, android, methods

I am doing a tutorial in Android app programming, and I am creating a program that allows the user to finger paint on the screen. The dot size is randomized, and I would like to have a label that tells you how big the dot is.

```
private void canvasTouched(int x, int y) {
    float dotSize = new Random().nextInt(33);
    myCanvas.DrawCircle(x, y, dotSize);
    lblStatus.Text("  touchX/touchY:" + x + "/" + y + " touches: " + ++numTouches);
}
```

This above code creates the size of the dot in the first two lines.

```
dotSize = new Label(hr);
dotSize.Text();
```

This code right here puts the `dotSize` label in a horizontal rule, and the second one puts in the text.

Now, should I have the `canvasTouched` method be changed to a float and return the size of the dot? How to I put that into the `dotSize.Text()` part?

Do I do something like:

```
dotSize.Text(canvasTouched.dotSize);
```

That code doesn't work, but what is proper syntax for getting the dot size?

Comment: canvasTouched() is a method... What are you expecting from canvasTouched.dotSize ??

Comment: I just want to be able to get the value of dotSize from the method.

Comment: That's not the right syntax to access a method. You can return the dotSize from the method and use it, or make dotSize as class member, so that it is accessible across the class.

Comment: The rest of the code looks curiously unlike android code as well.

Comment: You might also want to move the new Random() into an object attribute which you access in canvasTouched() otherwise you're creating a new random number *generator* each touch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rest of the code in that fragment isn't really code....

```
     DoubleFormatter df = new DoubleFormatter(4,6);
     String dotSizeText = df.format(dotSize);
     lblDotSize.setText(dotSizeText);
```

Kind of assuming you've run afoul of the overload of Label.setText that takes an integer resourceId argument (a string ID, not an integer).